# Displaying PCA with different colors

Tags: r, plot, pca

I have this data:

```
Desc     ALL1  ALL2  AML1  AML2
Gene1    -214  -342    87  -172
Gene2    -153  -200  -248  -122
Gene3    -58    41    262   38
Gene4     88    328   295   31
```

We have two types of tissues AML and ALL lukemia
I want to apply PCA to this data, so I tried doing this:

```
pca <- prcomp(x = all_aml_train_gct)
```

Now I want to plot it:

```
biplot(fit)
```

I get something like this:
[image: test plot]

How can I color the plot to distinguish ALL and AML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use a package called ggbiplot which enables a lot more flexibility in regards to the graphics. I have provided some code below that demonstrates its capabilities. Also, it is important to scale the variables when conducting PCA, which I am not sure if you did or not but just wanted to double check.

```
data("mtcars")

mtcars

# using cylinder as grouping variable, and weight and hp for example
cyl <- mtcars$cyl
cyl <- as.factor(cyl)
xvars <- mtcars[, c(4,7)]

# Need to scale variables for PCA due to the fact that variables with large variance will impact PCA 
xvars.scaled <- scale(xvars)

cars.pca <- prcomp(xvars.scaled)

# Create base plot
g.plot <- ggbiplot(cars.pca, obs.scale=1, var.scale=1,
               groups=cyl, ellipse=TRUE)

# Add in color
g.plot <- g.plot+ scale_color_discrete(name='')

# add in legend
g.plot <- g.plot+ theme(legend.direction='horizontal',
            legend.position='bottom')

g.plot
```

And the result is:

[image]

A more thorough example and tutorial can also be found at the following link: http://www.r-bloggers.com/computing-and-visualizing-pca-in-r/

I hope this helps!